# C++ class not is_trivially_copyable_v, is_copy_constructible_v, is_move_constructible_v, is_copy_assignable_v, is_move_assignable_v

Tags: c++, type-traits

I'm trying to create a class that is `is_trivially_copyable_v`, `is_copy_constructible_v`, `is_move_constructible_v`, `is_copy_assignable_v`, `is_move_assignable_v`. However, no matter how many types of constructors/assignment operators I add, it doesn't become trivially copyable. What could be wrong with the A class?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}


    A(A const& other)
    {
        s_ = other.s_;
    }


    A(A&& other)
    {
        s_ = other.s_;
    }

    A& operator=(const A&& other)
    {
        s_ = other.s_;
    }

private:

    std::string s_;
};



int main()
{
    static_assert(is_trivially_copyable_v<A>, "A");
    static_assert(is_copy_constructible_v<A>, "B");
    static_assert(is_move_constructible_v<A>, "C");
    static_assert(is_copy_assignable_v<A>, "D");
    static_assert(is_move_assignable_v<A>, "E");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Having a copy constructor stops your type from being trivially copyable, as does having a std::string member, [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable)

Comment: _"no matter how many types of constructors/assignment operators I add, it doesn't become trivially copyable"_. By definition, providing any user-provided (i.e. non-trivial) move/copy constructors or operators makes your class not [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Trivially_copyable_class)

Comment: In general, you don't _add_ until it's trivial.  You _subtract_.

Comment: Thanks, so it's not possible to do a class that contains a string and has these properties.

Comment: A `std::string` is not trivially copyable.  So anything containing a `std::string` is not trivial either.

Comment: I was trying to create this class in order to use it along with std::atomic, but it seems that it is not possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In short: `std::string` isn't trivially copyable, so your class containing one isn't either.

---

Whether a class type is trivially copyable has a set of [requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Trivially_copyable_class) you need to ensure.
**To grossly summarize**: Your copy and move constructors must be "trivial".
These have their own requirements ([copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Trivial_copy_constructor), [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Trivial_move_constructor)), notably:

- the constructor may not be user defined, i.e. it is implicitly defined or defaulted
- every non-static member must also be trivially copyable

If we check the [constructors of std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) we will find that the copy constructor is explicitly defined and it

> Constructs the string with a copy of the contents of `other`.

And I think this makes sense. The copy constructor of string copies the underlying data, which for all we know, can have arbitrary length. Copying that could be quite expensive and doesn't really sound "trivial".

Note that `char*` (and also `std::string_view` in C++23) is trivially copyable, but it doesn't provide ownership over the data, which raises a whole set of different questions.

---

> I was trying to create this class in order to use it along with std::atomic, but it seems that it is not possible.

If you want an "atomic string" you might want to consider putting into a shared pointer: `std::shared_ptr<std::string>`.

C++11 gave us [atomic functions for shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) and C++20 provides a specialization [`std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2).